# List comprehension not working in python

Tags: python, python-3.x, numpy, list-comprehension

Okay, so this code works fine for me.

```
a = [1, 2, 3, 4]
c = ['Three' if i is 3 else "Not Three" for i in a]
print(c)
```

Output:

```
['Not Three', 'Not Three', 'Three', 'Not Three']
```

But doing the same thing a bit more complexly, this code does not work. Where am I missing something?

```
import numpy as np

# 2 random np array of 10 elements ranging from -1 to 1
x = np.random.rand((10))*2 - 1
y = np.random.rand((10))*2 - 1

# xor = x>0 and y>0 or x<=0 and y<=0
xor = np.logical_or(
    np.logical_and(
        np.greater(x, 0), 
        np.greater(y, 0)), 
    np.logical_and(
        np.less_equal(x, 0), 
        np.less_equal(y, 0))
)
print(xor) # prints an array of random true and false of shape 200 

colors = np.array(['blue' if i is True else 'red' for i in xor])
# should print array of 'blue' and 'red' according to xor. But prints all 'red'
print(colors)
```

Outputs:

```
[ True  True False False  True  True  True False False  True]
['red' 'red' 'red' 'red' 'red' 'red' 'red' 'red' 'red' 'red']
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Don't use `is`:

```
colors = np.array(['blue' if i else 'red' for i in xor])
```

Comment: It worked! But please can you explain why `i is True` did not work?

Comment: Might have something to do with them being `numpy.bool`s.

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that your `xor` list is not a list of `bool`

Displaying the type of `i` in your loop provides this result:

```
print([type(i) if i == True else type(i) for i in xor])

[<class 'numpy.bool_'>, <class 'numpy.bool_'>, <class 'numpy.bool_'>, <class 'numpy.bool_'>, <class 'numpy.bool_'>, <class 'numpy.bool_'>, <class 'numpy.bool_'>, <class 'numpy.bool_'>, <class 'numpy.bool_'>, <class 'numpy.bool_'>]
```

Anytime you use the keyword `is` the item **must** be exactly the item being compared against.  There is exactly one value of `True` in the Python environment.  An `is` comparison compares your variable against that **one** value of True.

In your case, the variable i is never actually `True`, it's a numpy bool with some value.
An == compare would work as each side of the == is evaluated and a bool to bool comparison is made in the end.

However, as previously stated, the preferred form has no comparison at all.  `if i` is what you want.